# Ruby conditional regex flagging error: invalid conditional pattern (SyntaxError)

Tags: regex, ruby

I need a regex that is able to understand variables and arrays and extract data type, name of variable and array size (1D and 2D).

Example of strings:

```
first_string = "extern float variable;"
second_string = "extern uint8 array[5];"
thirds_string = "extern int16 map[10][4];"
```

My regex in ruby looks like this:

```
@regex = /^extern\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+\d*)(?(\[(\d*)\])\[(\d*)\];|;).*$/i
```

How I capture the data:

```
# line is a string
type, name, first_idx, second_idx = line.scan(@regex).flatten
```

What I am expecting to see:

```
first_string -> type(float), name(variable), first_idx(nil or ''), second_idx(nil or '')
second_string -> type(uint8), name(array), first_idx(5), second_idx(nil or '')
third_string -> type(int16), name(map), first_idx(10), second_idx(4)
```

The first section of the regex works great, but when I add the conditional expression to find the `[]` with the numbers I get the error.

I also tried using: `/^extern\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+\d*)\[*(\d*)\]*\[*(\d*)\]*;.*$/i` but the match of `[]` is only happening with the last regex.

Comment: Do you mean there can be max 2 repetitions of `[NUM]` at the end, before `;`?

Comment: Try `rx = /^extern\s+(?<type>\w+)\s+(?<name>\w+)(?:\[(?<first_idx>\d*)\])?(?:\[(?<second_idx>\d*)\])?;/` and then `s.match(rx).named_captures` (Ruby 2.4+). See Ruby 2.3 demo - https://ideone.com/KTHLBD and a Rubular [demo](https://rubular.com/r/OpAboq0H4rrRwW)

Comment: This seems like a task more complex then you'd want to use a regex for. Have you looked into writing a proper parser?